# Most frequently occuring neighbour (nltk)

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I need to write a function (which is part of a class) with which I can find the most frequently occuring neighbour (left and right) in a book of the gutenberg corpus. I'm somewhat lost ...

```
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
Class .......
.   def getNeighbour(self, word)
.       # code that gets neighbour
.    Return neighbour
```

Is there a built-in function in nltk to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1st make token of input string like

```
token = file_text.split(" ")
```

make bigram of this toekn using

```
def make_ngram(tokens, N=2):
    arr_ngram = []
    for i in range(len(tokens) - N + 1):
        arr_ngram.append(tokens[i:i + N])
    return arr_ngram
```

now calculate the frequency like this

```
 def calculate_frequency(arr_ngram):
    counts = {}
    for ngram in arr_ngram:
        token_seq = SPACE.join(ngram[:-1])
        last_token = ngram[-1]
        if token_seq not in counts:
            counts[token_seq] = {};
        if last_token not in counts[token_seq]:
            counts[token_seq][last_token] = 0;
        counts[token_seq][last_token] += 1;
    return counts;
```

the count will return all neighbor with their frequency. you can select highest frequency neighbor.